# Autenticar com o OAuth 2.0, Conta Azul, Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo dificuldade em finalizar o processo de Autenticando com o OAuth 2.0, achei alguns modelos, mas mesmo assim não consegui obter sucesso, essa é a Api https://developers.contaazul.com/, esse é modelo que preciso https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/FitBit.gs, pois ele tem que solicitar a autorização e gera o código de acesso para continuar o processo, e fazer as outras fases.

Está tudo criado as credenciais, estou parado na fase que pede para autorizar no log, já tentei várias maneiras de abrir um janela que  o usuário possa clicar e autorizar e guardar o código  da url de retorno mais não consegui, essa seria a biblioteca https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/README.md, já está habilitada no projeto.`

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxx';

/**
* Authorizes and makes a request to the FitBit API.
*/
function run() {
    var service = getService();
    if (service.hasAccess()) {
        var url = 'https://api.contaazul.com/v1/sales';
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
            }
        });
        var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    }else {
      var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
      Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',authorizationUrl);
    }
}

/**
* Reset the authorization state, so that it can be re-tested.
*/
function reset() {
    getService().reset();
}

/**
* Configures the service.
*/
function getService() {
    return OAuth2.createService('ContaAzul')
    // Set the endpoint URLs.      
 .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://api.contaazul.com/auth/authorize?')
 .setTokenUrl('https://api.contaazul.com/oauth2/token')

  // Set the client ID and secret.
  .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
  .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

  // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to
  // complete the OAuth flow.
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

  // Set the scope and additional headers required by the FitBit API.
  .setScope('sales')
  .setTokenHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' +
        Utilities.base64Encode(CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET)
  });
}

/**
* Handles the OAuth callback.
*/
function authCallback(request) {
    var service = getService();
    var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
    if (authorized) {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
    } else {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied.');
    }
 }

 /**
 * Logs the redict URI to register.
 */
 function logRedirectUri() {
     Logger.log(getService().getRedirectUri());
 }
```

Comment: Não sei se estou enganado, mas quando tentei usar a API do contazul, não deu muito certo não. Na verdade nem sei se de fato existe suporte para a mesma.

Comment: Também estou tentando integrar, mas não consegui fazer a autenticação.